# How do I add text on top of images in View Pager?

Tags: java, android, xml, database, android-viewpager

So my app as it stands is essentially a gallery containing 3 images. The user swipes from side to side to display the images. What I'm looking to add is text to the centre of the image (which I will be styling) but it needs to be different for every picture.

Here is my code for the project It's really simple right now.

main xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".InspireActivity" >

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
          android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main java

```
    public class Inspire extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inspire);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewAdapter adapter = new ViewAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inspire, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and my view pager java

```
public class ViewAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
R.drawable.mountain,
R.drawable.lake,
R.drawable.stars
};
ViewAdapter(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
}
```

I'm ultimately looking to have a singular database for both my images and text so that it's easy to add and remove them in the future. I'm also looking to possibly have my images and text fed from a website but that's for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xml layout to have text on top of an image. Any reason why you are not using xml to create your layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/how_to_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/how_to_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

look over the 'instantiateItem()' method [here](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/NumericPageIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/manuelpeinado/numericpageindicator/demo/MyPagerAdapter.java)

which dynamically builds textView. Try adding that chunk to your dynamic implementation so that the text and your image are children in a LinearLayout w/ ( vertical orientation ).

That should do it for you.

Note: there are lots of good ViewPager / Android projects on Github.